# How to modify django's request.user in a Middleware?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

What I'm trying to do is to detect the type of logged-in user and then setting a `.profile` parameter to `request.user`, so I can use it by calling `request.user.profile` in my views.

To do this, I've wrote a `Middleware` as follows:

```py
class SetProfileMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        user, token = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)
        profile_type = token.payload.get("profile_type", None)

        request.user.profile = User.get_profile(profile_type, request.user)
        request.user.profile_type = profile_type
        
        # Works Here
        print("-" * 20)
        print(type(request.user)) # <class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>
        print('Process Request ->', request.user.profile)


        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Does not work here
        print("-" * 20)
        print(type(request.user)) #  <class 'users.models.User'>
        print('Process Response ->', request.user.profile)


        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # Works here
        print("-" * 20)
        print(type(request.user)) # <class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>
        print('Process View ->', request.user.profile)
```

Now I can access `request.user.profile` in `process_view` however it does not exists in my views and is causing an `AttributeError` stating that `'User' object has no attribute 'profile'`.

Seems my `request.user` is being overwritten somewhere before hitting the view.

---

Note that I'm using Django Rest Framework, here is my view:

```py
class ProfileAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        obj = self.request.user.profile # Raise the `AttributeError`
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

Here is my `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

LOCAL_MIDDLEWARE = [
    "users.middleware.SetProfileMiddleware",
]

MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE + LOCAL_MIDDLEWARE

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=45),
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.SlidingToken",),
}

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "admin/"
```

Comment: How did you register the middleware? Please share the `settiings.py`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added some more details about my View and `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours to figure out what is going on, turned out that **SimpleJWT**'s `JWTAuthentication.authenticate()` method gets called just before the request hits the View, overwriting the `request.user` attribute.

So instead of trying to add the profile to the `request.user` using a middleware, I ended-up customizing `JWTAuthentication.authentication()` method:

```py
class CustomAuth(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):

        user, token = super().authenticate(request)

        profile_type = token.payload.get("profile_type", None)
        user.profile = User.get_profile((profile_type, user)
        user.profile_type = profile_type

        return user, token
```

`settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "users.authentication.CustomAuth"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot add new properties to the `User` class.

instead try to add the property directly to the request like this

`request.user_profile = User.get_profile(profile_type, request.user)`

```
def set_profile(view_function):
    
    def decorated_function(request, *args, **kwargs):

        user, token = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)
        profile_type = token.payload.get("profile_type", None)

        request.user_profile = User.get_profile(profile_type, request.user)
        request.user_profile_type = profile_type

        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function # No invocation here
```

Then in your function based view:

```
@api_view(["GET", "PUT"])
@set_profile
def my_view(request):
    request.user_profile # Will not throw attribute error
    ...
```

The only difference between function based view and class based view is that the decorator will receive `request` argument instead of `self`.

```
def set_profile(view_function):
    
    def decorated_function(self, *args, **kwargs):

        user, token = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(self.request)
        profile_type = token.payload.get("profile_type", None)

        self.request.user_profile = User.get_profile(profile_type, self.request.user)
        self.request.user_profile_type = profile_type

        return view_function(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function # No invocation here
```

Your class should look like this:

```
class ProfileAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

@set_profile
def get_object(self):
    obj = self.request.user_profile
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it has the same result as a class based middleware.

Comment: I've reviewed the code and the problem is you can't add properties to the User object.

You are trying to add .profile property to User.

Instead try to add .user_profile property to the request.

Comment: I just edited the answer.

If you really want to add the "profile" property to the User object, you either create a property for it (database column) or wrap it around a CustomUser class, which would require you to add AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser' to settings.py

Comment: It was  actually `simplejwt` overwriting the `request.user`.